# Cannot find optimize function for indices in elasticsearch python client

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch python client 6.4.0
I want to use the optimize API 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-optimize.html

But I could not find anything about it in the elasticsearch python api doc
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html

I tried using `es.indices.optimize(...)` but that function does not exist.

I will prefer to use the python client instead of direct API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a very old version of elastic (1.7). Optimize API was renamed to `forcemerge` and under this name it is available in python client ([docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.forcemerge))